# How to get phosphor-react icons working with NextJS server-side components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Next.js now recommends us to use App Dir, but, since everything are server-side rendered now by default, we shall put everything that needs interactivity on a component with "Use Client" flag.

The problem is that Phosphor React Icons are throwing errors when rendered on server side and I don't know how to get it working, since it's being used in some components which doesn't make sense being rendered client-side, should I create components for each icon I'm using only for wrapping each icon in "use client"?

When using phosphor-react icons in a server-side rendered component or page I get this error:

```
Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
  ./node_modules\@phosphor-icons\react\dist\lib\context.es.js
  ./node_modules\@phosphor-icons\react\dist\index.es.js
  ./src\app\page.tsx
```

Is wrapping each icon in a client-side component the right solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of Phosphor Icons. We've just added experimental support for server components in the latest build, which you can install manually via the @next tag, or using version >=2.1.3.

```
npm i @phosphor-icons/react@next
```

In order to use icons in server components, they must be imported from the /dist/ssr submodule:

```
import { Fish } from "@phosphor-icons/react/dist/ssr";
```

Comment: I think you meant `2.0.13`. Version `2.1.3` doesn't exist at the time of this writing, we're currently on `2.0.15`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but it's the one I'm currently using:

I created a folder at src/assets/icons/

Inside this folder I create a file for each icon I want to use and export them like this:

```
// assets/icons/MagnifyingGlass.tsx

'use client'

import { MagnifyingGlass } from '@phosphor-icons/react'

export default MagnifyingGlass
```

And any time I want to use them I import it from this assets folder.

Comment: @Kaio won't it increase the final bundle size? will the build process remove the unused exported icons?

Comment: @RicardoPassos yes! filipe just commented this on the comment below and it is really better to export only what you are using, so i'm deleting my comment for avoiding people to follow this bad suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to pinpoint that the suggestion proposed by @Kaio

```
"use client"; 
export * from "@phosphor-icons/react";
```

actually causes you to import all the icons from the library, which increases the bundle and may make your app to take longer to load. What I suggest doing instead is

```
"use client"; 
export {Icon1, Icon2} from "@phosphor-icons/react";
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Didn't consider this, make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you guys know that you can now import as such

```
import { ArrowRight } from "@phosphor-icons/react/dist/ssr/ArrowRight";
import { Basket } from "@phosphor-icons/react/dist/ssr/Basket";
```

So no more needing to do this yourself in order to reduce size.

I am using `"@phosphor-icons/react": "^2.1.3",`